# how can I apply C++ array in this?

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I apply C++ Array to this?
the picture above is the format/question.

[image: rray]

How can I apply C++ Array to this?
the picture above is the format/question.

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main(){

   int profit, monthly, Sales, Expenses;


   string Month[6] = {" January"," Febuary"," March"," April"," May","June"};

       float totalsales, totalexpenses, totalprofit;
           float sales[6] = {1000, 1500, 2500, 5000, 4000, 1800};
               float expenses[6] = {500, 250, 100, 1000, 200, 800};

   cout << "Company Sales and Expenses For 2020" << endl;           
   cout << "\nMonth" << "  Sales" << "  Expenses" << "  Profit" << endl;

   for (monthly=0; monthly<=6; monthly++){
   for (Sales=monthly; Sales<=monthly; Sales++)
        for (Expenses=monthly; Expenses<=monthly; Expenses++)
            for (int profit=monthly; profit<=monthly; profit++)
   cout << Month[monthly] << " " <<Sales[sales] << "   " <<Expenses[expenses] << "    _" << endl;
                    }


           
            cout << "\n\tSummary : " << endl;
            cout << "\t  Total Sales : " ;  cin  >> totalsales;
            cout << "\n\t Total Expenses : " ;  cin  >> totalexpenses;
            cout << "\n\t Total Profit : "; cin  >> totalprofit;
          

   }
```

Here is my code so far :(

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I apply C++ Array in this"? Are you asking how to use an `std::array`?

Comment: You are using arrays to store your data. The beginning of you code is OK. afterwards, in the for loop you should calculate profit for each line and increment the accumulators to obtain the final value (no need to use `cin`, these are values you must calculate in your for loop`.

Comment: What does your code do wrong? I don't want to have to figure that out myself so please describe it.

Comment: i need my program to look like the picture above

Comment: `for (monthly=0; monthly<=6; monthly++)` -- Off-by-one error.  What happens on the last iteration?  I suggest not writing loops with `<=` as a condition.

Comment: @Cedric22 *i need my program to look like the picture above* -- But you didn't notice the runtime errors?  Or you didn't know you had them?  You can't print anything looking like the picture if the program crashes.

Comment: @Cedric22 I understand that's what you need, but that doesn't tell me anything about what your program does incorrectly.

Comment: @Cedric22 I think the question should be two separate ones.  First, get the program not to crash and produce any (and all) output.  Then the second separate question (and different thread) would be to get the output to look as you want it to look.  So which one should this thread address?

Comment: my program isn't crashing, it's just i think there's a missing code/wrong input of code. I can't get my program to look like the picture above.

Comment: I appreciate you guys just by commenting and helping me out, its just that I'm having difficulty understanding the logic of making that output using array

Comment: When looking closer at your assignment, I noticed that it doesn't actually say that you should calculate the profit _or_ the totals. It just has a note that says `Profit = Sales - Expenses` at the bottom - and April and May seems to be excluded in the wanted output.

Comment: about the april may thing, i think its just what my prof wanted us to fill that

Comment: @Cedric22 -- *my program isn't crashing* -- Accessing items out-of-bounds leads to undefined behavior.  Your program has this error.  For example, your program [crashes here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9a81e451122e3d6), (see the error `bash: line 7: 12545 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out`)? but an out-of-bounds access doesn't guarantee a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code is a mess. Next time go through some tutorials, so that you know how to work with basic elements of language (e.g. loops, arrays,..).

Now to get to the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

   int profit;

   string Month[6] = {" January"," February"," March"," April"," May","June"};

   int totalSales = 0;
   int totalExpenses = 0;
   int totalProfit = 0;
   int sales[6] = {1000, 1500, 2500, 5000, 4000, 1800};
   int expenses[6] = {500, 250, 100, 1000, 200, 800};

   cout << "Company Sales and Expenses For 2020" << endl;           
   cout << "\nMonth" << "\tSales" << "\tExpenses" << "\tProfit" << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
       profit = sales[i] - expenses[i];
       totalSales += sales[i];
       totalExpenses += expenses[i];
       totalProfit += profit;
       cout << Month[i] << "\t" << sales[i] << "\t" << expenses[i] << "\t" << profit << endl;
   }
   cout << "\nSummary : " << endl;
   cout << "\tTotal Sales : " << totalSales << endl;
   cout << "\tTotal Expenses : " << totalExpenses << endl;
   cout << "\tTotal Profit : " << totalProfit << endl;
              
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, but remember @Cedric22 that you have to learn the basics, so that you don't create such a bad code, like you did.

Comment: @AP11 Unnecessary comment. OP _is_ learning. This was an assignment.

Comment: sir can you recommend me to a site or video about array and c++ stuff? I'm having a hard time using my prof examples as reference. thank you very much ! :)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I know, but he should know how difference between `std::cout` and `std::cin`, which he clearly doesn't know. Same can be applied to all of basic language properties, that are easily obtained by doing some kind of tutorial.

Comment: @Cedric22 I started with Java, as it seemed easier for beginner to learn programming 101, but you can find hundreds of them on the internet.

In my eyes, you should watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUQZ1qmKlLY&t=15950s)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying my best.

Comment: @Cedric22 I know, the beginnings are hard, but try to learn basics first, and then advance as you'll have a good foundation.

Comment: @Cedric22 Best of luck in your programming career!

Comment: thank you very much sir, i'll try my best.